# jquery div onclick call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html

I need to setup a onclick where if you click on the div with the id of "version" it calls the below script.

html

```
<div id="version">CONTINUE</div>
```

js

```
if (/Android\s+([\d\.]+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ 
 var anversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) 
 if (anversion=<3)
  window.location = 'main2.html'
 }
else
 window.location = 'main.html'
```

Comment: Useragent sniffing can be a bad practice.. just an FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#version").click(function() {
  // Your code here...
});
```

For more details see [the jQuery API on *.click()*](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

**EDIT:** I also corrected your code. It then looks like this:

```
if(/Android\s+([\d\.]+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { 
  var anversion = parseInt(RegExp.$1);
  if(anversion <= 3) {
    window.location.href = 'main2.html';
  } else {
    window.location.href = 'main.html';
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but Im not even redirected to main.html on click

Comment: That is, because your code is buggy. Please use `window.location.href = 'main.html';` and set appropiate semicolons.

Comment: The code only redirects on Android browsers. Are you running the code on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#version").click(function() {
    if (/Android\s+([\d\.]+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { 
        window.location.href = Number(RegExp.$1) <= 3 ? 'main2.html' : 'main.html';
    }
});
```

Your code has errors.

- `anversion=<3` should be `anversion <= 3`
- `new Number(RegExp.$1)` should be `Number(RegExp.$1)` otherwise you *create* an object instead of converting string to number.